# Reliable DIY Virtual Landscaping Design apps

Tags: web-apps, landscape

Has anyone had success in DIY landscaping via an app?

I'm redesigning my rooftop to include lounge area and greenspace but would like virtual professional guidance as I build it out and do so via "social distance". Here's a summary of my rooftop layout today--

One-third of my current rooftop is covered with elevated wood tiles, and the remaining 2/3 is bare roof. I'd like to consider a few options across the full rooftop:

- turf installation
- space buildout & design (including vertical structures)
- furniture & accessories

Ideally I'd look for a landscaping app that can

- provide visual recommendations based on my actual space, layout and idea preferences with real-view preview of the options
- provide specificity to products, prices and purchase locations to complete a project
- option of a design consultant to help make slight tweaks and answer questions

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something similar and found this top-rated app, which appears to have at least most of the features you're seeking: [iScape](https://www.iscapeit.com/)

Comment: The question tag is for a web app. iScape seems to be a phone app.